# Is it possible to send UDP stream to browser?

Tags: html, udp, streaming, video-streaming

On a college project I need to stream videos from a server to a web client using UDP protocol. I've been searching everywhere but haven't found a solution.

Comment: The only one I am aware of is QUIC. And thats only supported in chrome I believe. Otherwise you are looking at a custom plugin.

Answer (score 1):

UDP video streaming isn't really supported directly in the browser. You could send your stream using RTP over UDP but you'll need a browser plugin to play it. Some examples include the VLC, RealPlayer, QuickTime web plugins.

Comment: @Diego, and you could look to WebChimera plugin (http://WebChimera.org) - it's based on libvlc.

Comment: @RSATom that URL seems to be broken, the project is still on: https://github.com/RSATom/WebChimera however it is deprecated.